# How to solve Easy Paisa (Easy Pay) Payment Gate Integration Error Invalid Authentication Token

Tags: java, android, payment

> In my project I am trying to integrate Easy payment gateway but I am
>   receiving `INVALID AUTHENTICATION TOKEN` in my `WebView`.

```
E/purl: https://easypaystg.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/Index.jsf
E/token: https://easypaystg.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/Index.jsf
E/posturl: https://easypaystg.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/Index.jsf
E/purl: ://easypaystg.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/faces/pg/site/AuthError.jsf
E/purl: https://easypaystg.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/Confirm.jsf
D/AwareBitmapCacher: handleInit switch not opened pid=27748
I/HwViewRootImpl: removeInvalidNode all the node in jank list is out of time
E/purl https://easypaystg.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/faces/pg/site/AuthError.jsf
E/chromium: [ERROR:page_load_metrics_update_dispatcher.cc(165)] Invalid first_paint 2

public class Payment_details extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;
    String postData = null;
    private RelativeLayout mConfirm;
    String data;
    boolean isFirst = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.payment_details);
        mConfirm = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.pd_confirm);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.pdwebView);
        data = "https://easypaystg.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/Index.jsf";
        Log.e("data", data);
        try {

            postData = URLEncoder.encode("amount", "UTF-8")
                    + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("100.0", "UTF-8");

            postData += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("storeId", "UTF-8") + "="
                    + URLEncoder.encode("xxxxx", "UTF-8");

            postData += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("postBackURL", "UTF-8")
                    + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("https://easypaystg.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/Confirm.jsf", "UTF-8");

            postData += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("orderRefNum", "UTF-8")
                    + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("121212121", "UTF-8");


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.postUrl(data, postData.getBytes());

    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);


            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            Log.e("purl", url);
            if (isFirst) {
                isFirst = false;
                try {
                    String[] ist = url.split("=");
                    String[] snd = ist[0].split("&");
                    String Token = snd[0];

                    Log.e("token", Token);
                    Log.e("posturl", ist[0]);
                    secondredirect(Token, view);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(Payment_details.this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);


        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            handler.proceed();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    }

    private void secondredirect(String token, WebView view) {
        String sData = null;
        String sURL = "https://easypaystg.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/Confirm.jsf";
        try {
            sData = URLEncoder.encode("auth_token", "UTF-8")
                    + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(token, "UTF-8");

            sData += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("postBackURL", "UTF-8") + "="
                    + URLEncoder.encode("https://easypaystg.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/Confirm.jsf", "UTF-8");
            view.postUrl(sURL, sData.getBytes());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "UnsupportedEncodingException: "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1288408/modus-tollens    E/purl: E/token: https://easypaystg.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/Index.jsf
E/posturl: https://easypaystg.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/Index.jsf
E/purl: ://easypaystg.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/faces/pg/site/AuthError.jsf
E/purl: https://easypaystg.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/Confirm.jsf
D/AwareBitmapCacher: handleInit switch not opened pid=27748
I/HwViewRootImpl: removeInvalidNode all the node in jank list is out of time
E/purl https://easypaystg.easypaisa.com.pk/easypay/faces/pg/site/AuthError.jsf